# What's inappropriate with the Q&A style question that some people keep trying to close my post?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

I've posted a question with how I solve a series of my related question on SO

- [How to find out the type for assign from/to another type in c#? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472103/how-to-find-out-the-type-for-assign-from-to-another-type-in-c/14472104#14472104)

I'd like to understand what I've done was inappropriate that some willing to close my question?

I've tried to correct it with revised many times. But I can't get an idea of why there's some people keep trying to close my post?

Comment: That post was never deleted

Comment: That's not a question and answer, that's a blog post.

Comment: What's with all the stuff below "update"? That really shouldn't be there.

Comment: As an unrelated question, why have you destroyed the content of several of your answers, then deleted them, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14486813/19679 ? Why have you gone through and flagged all of those for moderator action? What are we supposed to be doing about them?

Comment: I would have gone with *not a real question*.

Comment: @Brad Larson: Because I when deleted a answer, I see it still there.

Comment: "Deleted" posts are never really deleted.

Comment: @KenKin - Deletion just removes something from public view. You can still see these, as the owner of the post, in case you want to edit and undelete them. If these answers contain sensitive content, the devs can hard-delete them manually, but it takes a little work to do. If you need that, you can let us know, but there's no need to edit or flag these otherwise.

Comment: And please don't [do stuff like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110549/488657). You ask an equally sized question and then self-answer it by merely linking to yet another post on SO and one on another SE site altogether. It creates a jumble of intertwined content. That's not good.

Comment: Your question is also very unclear. And I'm pretty proficient in C# and .NET.  What are you asking here?  If I'm asking this, the question should be *closed*, while you edit the question into something more comprehensive.  Asking and answering your own questions is encouraged, but the question has to be of equal quality to the answer.  The quality of an answer doesn't prop up a weak question.  That said, clearly explain what you're trying to do, as well as show what you've tried (original research effort) and retool the answer as appropriate.

Comment: @KenKin And thank you for being constructive about this. You are obviously willing to provide the site with extensive and in-depth content. Absolutely brilliant and appreciated. But keep it structured and to the point. The format is pretty much dictated by the site. Question and Answer. Ask a self-contained question and answer it.

Comment: Thanks all of you. I'll find a better translation tool.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Referring to [this revision before the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14472103/20), what is the actual question you're asking? Is it the content above "update"? If so, limit it to that. There is no need for the rest. Let's have a look at it:

> Suggest to be reopened as a resource to help people who dealing with types and reflection.

That should not be part of the question. A comment at most? But even that would be noise.

> This is a It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions question.

Once again, not part of the question. Nobody cares.

> The answer by myself may also applies to the questions of others:

So? Answer those questions. And if they are all suited by the same single answer, you might want to consider if they are not duplicates.

> And this question is related to following previous questions of myself:

Who cares? This is not your personal blog. We don't need an entire history of previously asked questions. We need a good single question related to a practical problem you face (or in the case of a self-answer, have faced)

> In those questions, I defined three method with the same length of name, they are:

No, don't make us read through previous questions to get what it is you're trying to tell us here. I don't want to read your entire series or previous content. I want you to ask me a single, self-contained question.

All in all it's a bit of a mess. And I for one can certainly understand this getting closed.

Focus. Ask a single question related to a practical problem you (have) face(d) and answer it if you can. That's it. There is no need for all the rest. Q&A, question and answer. Not a blog post.

Comment: The series of related questions were what I face to. I guess that if you were always the first one to answer, I probably get them solved early. But I think that we should be etiquette, right? Been a newbie to SE, I feel that I'm not friendly treated.

Comment: Don't confuse close votes or downvotes with unfriendliness. Stack Overflow (or Stack Exchange) is pretty strict in its format and what is considered good content. It is actively community moderated to keep the standards up. Take the votes as a lesson. Learn from them. Nobody is telling you you're terrible. If anything the closure of your question is a good time to address the problems with the post and have it reopened (which has happened now). And it protects other users from answering a question which will (our should) ultimately be changed. It might take some getting used to, but you will.

Comment: I'm not confused with votes but words. It might because of I'm a foreigner, I don't read them naturally, I keep referring to dictionaries. I tried my best to express and to understand what people are expressing.

Comment: If there is anything in particular you don't understand of what I've said, feel free to ask for clarification. I can imagine it must be daunting if you don't fluently speak a language. But you seem to be doing fine. If you find some people are truly rude, feel free to flag their messages for moderator attention. That truly is not tolerated on the site.

Comment: Thank to Google Translation. But I think I need a better one. And thank you very much. I'll keep learning.