# Is it welcome to ask "what's wrong with my answer" on Meta?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I recently asked: [Should I keep my answer there?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173409/should-i-keep-my-answer-there)

And now I have a answer that appears to be not helpful and should be deleted:

[Should all objects have an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672950/should-all-objects-have-an-interface/15673606#15673606)

By good person's suggestion, to ask *what's wrong with my answer* on Meta, then I come to ask, for being some more careful to delete.

I want to know if these questions are welcome on Meta?

Comment: It seems my edit was both approved and rejected.

Comment: From [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672950/should-all-objects-have-an-interface/15673606#15673606) question: `I'm ignoring the original statement of question`. Looks like people didn't take too kindly to that.

Comment: @BlahBlahGrabblesnackers: Would you give me some idea to correct that? What I mean by that is I would temporarily put the directly thinking of question away and then by a reverse thinking and then back to the original description.

Comment: @hjpotter92: I approved but don't know what happened then.

Comment: @KenKin - removing that statement may help; running it through a spell checker to clean up the grammar, and come to a concise point, may help too.

Comment: @BlahBlahGrabblesnackers: I revised it. But I seem not have some words in shorter than I typed in the comment above.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I'm removing that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a personal opinion, I would not mind these questions, with a few exceptions:

- Questions that are clearly within (or out of) the bounds given by the FAQ.
- Questions that are duplicates.
- Users that ask about each of their questions (or each of the questions that received a down-vote).

Interesting are the edge cases, and those that are with the spirit of the FAQ but which are not clearly defined, because these could lead to a better definition in the FAQ. And that will benefit us all in the end.

Comment: The OP is asking about Answers, not Questions. Does your answer still apply to users asking about what's wrong with their *Answer* on meta?

Comment: @Rachel: Although I didn't really know what's wrong with my answer after all, but this answer seems saying that it's no problem to ask question like *what's wrong with my answer* on Meta thus answered the question as the title says, and so accepted.